# Dataframe split row data into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe like this

```
Name Val
A    1;2;3;4;5
B    10;20;30;40;50
C    11;22;33;44;55
D    a;b;c;d;e
E    0.0;0.1;0.2;0.3;0.4
```

I need to convert it into a df like below

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   10  11  a   0.0
2   20  22  b   0.1
3   30  33  c   0.2
4   40  44  d   0.3
5   50  55  e   0.4
```

I wrote the below code to get the required output.

```
df_x = pd.DataFrame([['A','1;2;3;4;5'],
                 ['B','10;20;30;40;50'],
                 ['C','11;22;33;44;55'],
                 ['D','a;b;c;d;e'],
                 ['E', '0.0;0.1;0.2;0.3;0.4']], columns=['NAME','VAL'])
print(df_x, '\n')

new_dict = dict()

for idx,row in df_x.iterrows():
    new_dict[row['NAME']] = row['VAL'].split(';')

df_y = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
print(df_y)
```

But if there are thousands of data in **VAL** column, then I suspect this is not a very efficient way to get the output. Is there any other way to make this more efficient? (*like not using a separate dictionary and try something within the dataframe or anyother way*)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = df_x.set_index('NAME')['VAL'].str.split(';', expand=True).rename_axis(None).T
print(df, '\n')
   A   B   C  D    E
0  1  10  11  a  0.0
1  2  20  22  b  0.1
2  3  30  33  c  0.2
3  4  40  44  d  0.3
4  5  50  55  e  0.4
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks.